# I want to draw Hasse diagram in table, how can I do?

Tags: tables, diagrams

[image]

I want to draw Hasse diagram of some partial order relations on common universal set in tabular representation. An example of this is as in the picture (of course, it has to be math form). Unfortunately, I can't do it with LaTeX. Is there anyone who can help me with this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

• Note this is a Q&A site, not a please do this for me service. What do you have so far.

Comment: Maybe have a look at tikz and tabular. There are a number of questions on texexchange about Hasse diagrams, that might give you a start.

Comment: @albert \documentclass{article}, this is all i have.

Comment: Best To study some LaTeX and examples and try to get a MWE.

Comment: @albert I try to use "xy" package in tabular, but unfortunately could not be drawn

Comment: Show what you have som people might have a chance to help you / give some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `tikzpicture`s in a table like anything else. This is to give you a start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{*4{|c}|}
  \hline
   & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \cline{2-4}
  \multirow{-4}{*}{$(F,A)$}
  &\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node(2){$2$}  + (90:1) node (c){$c$}  + (0:1) node(b){$b$};
    \draw[-stealth] (2) -- (c);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  &\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path node (c){$c$}   + (-120:1) node(2){$2$}    + (-60:1) node(b){$b$};
    \draw[-stealth] (c) -- (2);
    \draw[-stealth] (c) -- (b);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  &\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text height=1.6em}]
    \path node(2){$2$} + (0.5,0) node(b){$b$} + (1,0) node(c){$c$};
   \end{tikzpicture}\\
   \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{Hasse diagrams in a table.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, it is very helpful. Thanks again.